# 6-sides dice numbered from 1 to 6

Tags: probability

A 6-sided dice has faces numbered 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 , when it is thrown the number facing up is the score , if it is thrown three times.
 
a) Find the probability that the total score is 18.
b) Find the probability that the score on the third throw is exactly the double of the score of the first two throws.

My turn :

The possibilities for a is just one possibility which is the three throws have the number 6 , then the answer is $$\frac{1}{216}$$

The possibilities for b are two , which are the third has the number 6 and the second and the first have 1 and 2 or 2 and 1
The the answer is $$\frac{2}{216}$$
Do these answers sound correct ?

Comment: There are three different ways to get the second case: $114$, $126$ and $216.$

Comment: For (a) that is correct, leaving it unsimplified as $\frac{1}{6^3}$ might have been easier to verify however.  As for (b), that depends on your interpretation of what the problem is asking.  If we are adding the score of the first two and multiplying the sum by two to decide what the third die should be, then you forgot about the possibility of both of the first two dice being a $1$ and the third die being a $4$.  If what is being asked is instead that the third die is double the first die as well as double the second die, eg 112, 224, 336, then that gets a different answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it!

The first one is good.

For the second one, you missed the possibility that the two first dice show 1 and 1, and the third shows 4. So the probability is actually $\frac{3}{216}=\frac1{72}$.